# How to execute two tasks at same time

Tags: python, celery

I'm working with celery that I encountered a problem.

I have two functions:
1) This function will be activated when the program is activated, and it will work infinitely:

```
from celery.signals import worker_ready    

@worker_ready.connect()
def message_poll_start(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("hello")
```

2) This function will be activated every ten seconds and write a date in a txt file:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10))
def last_record_time_check():
    file_text = open('file.txt', 'a')
    file_text.write("===========" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) +
                    " =============== \n\n")
```

and finally I used [celeryd](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#init-script-celeryd) and [celerybeat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#init-script-celerybeat)

The first function works without problems, but the second function does not work at all.

```
[2018-02-06 16:43:17,802: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2018-02-06 16:43:27,947: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task base.tasks.last_record_time_check (base.tasks.last_record_time_check)
[2018-02-06 16:43:37,925: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task base.tasks.last_record_time_check (base.tasks.last_record_time_check)
[2018-02-06 16:43:47,926: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task base.tasks.last_record_time_check (base.tasks.last_record_time_check)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AdrienLogut, sorry, added in last line

Comment: @Alfe You actually didn't downvote.

Comment: Right.  But there is no `http://ifoundatypicalfl.aw`, there only is a `http://idownvotedbecau.se` ;-)

Comment: How many worker processes do you start?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is stuck on first one, as it is always in while loop.