# Run task once after celery worker started

Tags: python, celery

I need to run a task right after a celery worker is up and ready to work. Not really sure where to start. Quick search online did not give anythin concrete - the closest was recommendation to use http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html?highlight=signals#celeryd-after-setup
Anybody has better recommendations?

Comment: Have a look at this guy's question, maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648011/how-to-execute-two-tasks-at-same-time

Comment: @Gre0ry not sure how that will help me :-(

Comment: The question contains code sample where you can see '''@worker_ready.connect()''' - is that not what you are looking for?